# How to find unique pattern of hex from binary file using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, binary, hex

***Here I got a binary file of 4GB. And I want to search for hex pattern in That file and get offset of required pattern.***

The pattern look like `?? ?? ?? E5 00 60 8F E0 ?? ?? ?? E5 04 00 80 E0` the **?(question marks)** are unknown points.

**Python code to get 16 bytes hex code is**

```
with open("file.bin", 'rb') as in_file:
    while True:
        hexdata = in_file.read(16).hex().upper()
        if len(hexdata) == 0:
            break
```

***Returns sample code like***

---

```
17000000ECBDD40617000000F0BDD406
17000000F4BDD40617000000F8BDD406
17000000FCBDD4061700000000BED406
1700000004BED4061700000008BED406
170000000CBED4061700000010BED406
FAEEF0E500608FE0A0EAFFE5040080E0
```

---

I am trying this regex pattern to find desire pattern.
**pattern = "[a-f0-9]{6}[E500608FE0][a-f0-9]{6}[E5040080E0]"**

But it return None.
If I am doing something wrong let be know.

***Answer***

```
import re
pattern = "[A-F0-9]{6}(E500608FE0)[A-F0-9]{6}(E5040080E0)"

with open("file.bin", 'rb') as in_file:
        while True:
            hexdata = in_file.read(16).hex().upper()
            if len(hexdata) == 0:
                break
            if re.search(pattern, hexdata):
                print("found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`[A-F0-9]{6}(E500608FE0)[A-F0-9]{6}(E5040080E0)`

https://regex101.com/r/cBrlcW/1